# sqlite query - select all older than X days, not Y newest

Tags: sqlite

my sqlite table has following format (all not null and not unique INTEGER for example):

```
time        type data
1436268660  0    ...
1436268661  1    ...
1436268662  0    ...
1436268666  2    ...
1436268668  1    ...
```

Sometimes I need to delete all rows of each type which are older than some time but I need to leave 5 newest from each type even if they are older than that specific time.
In other words, to leave 5 newest rows of each type and also all newer than specified time (if there is more than 5) and to delete the rest.

So, if the specified time is X and type 0 has 20 rows newer than X, nothing is done for type 0 (all are new enough).
Also if the specified time is X and type 0 has 5 rows all older than X, nothing is done (there is not more than 5 of them).
But if there is for example 7 entries and at least 2 of them are older than X, then those 2 oldest are deleted.

What I have so far is this query. But it is not correct. It just deletes all rows older than X when there is more than 5 of that type. If they are all older than X nothing is left.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid IN 
  (SELECT table.rowid FROM table JOIN
    (SELECT type FROM table GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(*) > 5) 
  USING (type) WHERE TIME < 14362685399);
```

As you can see the situation is little bit more complicated as "type" described above by me is in reality unique combination of multiple columns (you can replace by type1,type2,type3), but I guess it is not so important for the solution.
Thank you for any help.

```
time        type0 type1 type2 data
1436268660  0     0     0     ...
1436268661  1     1     1     ...
1436268662  0     0     0     ...
1436268666  2     2     2     ...
1436268668  1     1     1     ...
```

Edit: Basically I need to delete all rows NOT in: (newer than X) UNION (5 latest entries for each type). **I just don't know how to create result with "5 latest entries for each type"**.

Comment: what is the table definition (the column type for time, e.g.)

Comment: TIME is DATETIME type, but it could be just INTEGER number where I search for "bigger than", "less than" I guess. TYPE columns are integers, the rest is probably not important.

Comment: everything not null, everything not unique

Comment: Consider edtiting the question with the additional information

Comment: INTEGER not null not unique type info added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I've renamed your table to `t`.

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE rowid IN(
  SELECT a.rowid FROM t a
  WHERE time < 14362685399
  AND a.rowid NOT IN (
    SELECT b.rowid FROM t b
    WHERE a.type = b.type
    ORDER BY b.time DESC
    LIMIT 5
  )
);
```

Note that this may not be very efficient on large data, due to the [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) which will be evaluated each time it is required (possibly once per distinct `type` in your table, or maybe even once per row in the table, depending on how the query is executed).

As an aside, in a SQL variant that supports it, this would probably be better achieved with a window function. For example, in [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's it, quite simple in the end :-) Of course such subquery will be probably slow. If the performance will be very poor, I will have to do the check with each insert only for inserted row or something like that... we will see.